# Xml widget Properties won't load

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, settings

I have a problem with the Properties window in Android Studios. The problem is that the properties won't load. Like in the Picture, it only shows Loading and it's symbol, but nothing happens. I have already waited for more than five minutes but it still happens nothing. All other windows work peferctly. I restarted it many times and also tried the Invalid Caches / Restart option.
Hope you can help me.
Kingsten
[Screenshot of the properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tZPG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I have deleted the C:\Users\S4Kin.AndroidStudio2.3 and started with new Settings(rebuild the settigns)